# mySQL query for max timestamp yesterday

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'm looking to get the maximum timestamp from yesterday. Storing data as datetime.

Db layout is table name: earnings

Coloumns: id, earnings, timestamp

Currently doing command:

```
SELECT earnings, timestamp FROM earnings WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM earnings)
```

Now I would like to get the highest timestamp from yesterday.... Please let me know the best way of doing this through either mySQL or PHP and mySQL.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT earnings, timestamp 
FROM earnings 
WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) 
                   FROM earnings
                   WHERE DATE(timestamp) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 DAY))
```

or

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    earnings a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT MAX(timestamp) max_Date
            FROM earnings
            WHERE DATE(timestamp) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 DAY)
        ) b ON a.timestamp = b.max_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Why everyone likes subselects so much?

```
SELECT * FROM earnings ORDER BY timestamp DESC limit 1
```

for your first query, and

```
SELECT * FROM earnings WHERE timestamp < CURDATE() ORDER BY timestamp DESC limit 1
```

for the second

Comment: I agree with this one but it doesn't handle ties on records which have maximum timestamp.